# Converting to decimal using sql statement

Tags: sql

i have decimal numbers like in the table below, im trying to convert them to decimal, because when i select them, they are come out as integer, for example on row 1 if i select 0.8 or 2.86 it will give me 0 or 2 respectively

[image: table in the database]

im using the following statement

```
select ELERENVPR, ELEDCSFPM from db-name
```

i tried cast to convert it

```
select cast(ELERENVPR, decimal), cast(ELEDCSFPM,decimal) from db-name
```

im not sure if it works, becouse now its renaming the table to 00001 and 00002, like the picture below

[image]

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Whenever you wrap a column in ***any*** function *(including `CAST`)*, it's no longer the original column and so ***you*** need to give the result of the expression a column name...  `SELECT cast(ELERENVPR, decimal(10,2)) AS newELERENVPR`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decimal` with no scale or precision parameters has defaults, which might be to zero precision.

You need to be explicit about what you want.  I would recommend something like `decimal(10, 2)` (8 digits before the decimal place, 2 after).  Something like this:

```
select cast(ELERENVPR, decimal(10, 2)) as ELERENVPR,
       cast(ELEDCSFPM, decimal(10, 2)) as ELEDCSFPM
from db-name ;
```

The `as` renames the columns.